# Swift: Output file of AssetWriter not available to AVAsset on first creation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am creating a video out of an image and then need to access it right away. I am creating it by adding an `imageBuffer` of the image to an `AVAssetWriter`. The video is created here:

```swift
while !adaptor.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData { usleep(10) }
let first = adaptor.append(buffer, withPresentationTime: startFrameTime)
while !adaptor.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData { usleep(10) }
let second = adaptor.append(buffer, withPresentationTime: endFrameTime)

videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
videoWriter.finishWriting {
    completion(videoWriter.error)
}
```

Both first and second return true (successful appends) and there is no error on videoWriter. The video has successfully been created. I can successfully "retrieve" the asset upon its completion with

```swift
makeVideo(image, urlDestination) { error in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    let imageAsset = AVAsset(url: url)

    guard
        let imageTrack = self.composition.addMutableTrack(
            withMediaType: .video,
            preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
        let imageVideoTrack = imageAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
    }

    try! imageTrack.insertTimeRange(
        CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: self.duration), 
        of: imageVideoTrack, 
        at: .zero
    )

    let imageVideoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: imageTrack)
}
```

However, the first time I try to access it I don't get any video (there is a video track with the right duration, but with no video of any sort being displayed). If I add it to a PreviewController I get nothing. However, if I dismiss the PreviewController, and access the asset a second time, then it is successful.

My first thought was that this is a potential timing issue, but even if I add a delay it fails the first time.

Any thoughts? Keep in mind that this code works for when the file at the url already exists; just not right after it is made.

Edit:
The above are the parts of code I think are pertinent to this question. Fuller code is as below:

```swift
private func filePath() -> URL {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    guard let documentDirectory = urls.first else {
        fatalError("documentDir Error")
    }

    return documentDirectory
}

class VideoComposer {
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    let duration: CMTime
    let videoSize: CGSize

    var viewSizeMultiplier: CGFloat = 5.0

    init(view: UIView) {

        videoSize = CGSize(width: 1772.0, height: 3840.0)
        viewSizeMultiplier = 1772.0 / view.frame.width

        self.duration = CMTime(seconds: 15, preferredTimescale: 600)
        mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: self.duration)

        view.subviews.reversed().forEach { subview in
            if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView {
                addImage(of: imageView)
            }
            else {
                print("unhandled view type")
            }
        }
    }

    func createVideo(completion: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession) -> Void) {

        // make video composition
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 60)
        videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize

        export(videoComposition: videoComposition) { (session) in
            completion(session)
        }
    }

    private func export(videoComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition, completion: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession) -> Void) {
        // export
        let url = filePath().appendingPathComponent("output.mov")

        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
            try! fileManager.removeItem(at: url)
        }

        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
        exporter.outputFileType = .mov
        exporter.outputURL = url

        exporter.exportAsynchronously {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(exporter)
            }
        }
    }

    private func addImage(of imageView: UIImageView) {
        guard let image = imageView.image else {
            assertionFailure("no image")
            return
        }

        let movieLength = TimeInterval(duration.seconds)

        let url = filePath().appendingPathComponent("image.mov")

        ImageVideoCreator.writeSingleImageToMovie(image: image, movieLength: movieLength, outputFileURL: url) { [weak self] success in

            guard let `self` = self else {
                return
            }

            let imageAsset = AVAsset(url: url)

            let keys = ["playable", "readable", "composable", "tracks", "exportable"]
            var error: NSError? = nil

            imageAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    keys.forEach({ key in
                        let status = imageAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: key, error: &error)
                        switch status {
                        case .loaded:
                            print("loaded. \(error)")
                        case .loading:
                            print("loading. \(error)")
                        case .failed:
                            print("failed. \(error)")
                        case .cancelled:
                            print("cancelled. \(error)")
                        case .unknown:
                            print("unknown. \(error)")
                        }
                    })

                    guard
                        let imageTrack = self.composition.addMutableTrack(
                            withMediaType: .video,
                            preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
                        let imageVideoTrack = imageAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
                        else {
                            assertionFailure()
                            return
                    }

                    try! imageTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: self.duration), of: imageVideoTrack, at: .zero)

                    let imageVideoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: imageTrack)

                    print("image")

                    self.setTransform(on: imageVideoLayerInstruction, of: imageView, andOf: imageVideoTrack)
                    self.mainInstruction.layerInstructions.append(imageVideoLayerInstruction)
                }
            })
       }
   }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var composer: VideoComposer?
    let player = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let pathUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb", withExtension: "mp4") else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }

        let image = UIImage(named: "image")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image!.size.width / 4).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image!.size.height / 4).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        composer = VideoComposer(view: view)

        composer?.createVideo() { exporter in
            self.didFinish(session: exporter)
        }
    }

    func didFinish(session: AVAssetExportSession) {
        guard let url = session.outputURL else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        self.showVideo(videoUrl: url)
    }

    func showVideo(videoUrl: URL) {
        let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        player.player = videoPlayer

        self.present(player, animated: true) {
            self.player.player?.play()
        }
    }
}

class ImageVideoCreator {

    private static func pixelBuffer(fromImage image: CGImage, size: CGSize) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        let options: CFDictionary = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String: true, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String: true] as CFDictionary
        var pxbuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(size.width), Int(size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, options, &pxbuffer)

        guard let buffer = pxbuffer, status == kCVReturnSuccess else {
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, [])
        guard let pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer) else {
            return nil
        }

        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer)

        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        guard let context = CGContext(data: pxdata, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }
        context.concatenate(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0))
        context.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, [])

        return buffer
    }

    static func writeSingleImageToMovie(image: UIImage, movieLength: TimeInterval, outputFileURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: outputFileURL.path) {
            try! fileManager.removeItem(at: outputFileURL)
        }

        do {
            let imageSize = image.size

            let videoWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputFileURL, fileType: AVFileType.mov)
            let videoSettings: [String: Any] = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                                                AVVideoWidthKey: imageSize.width,
                                                AVVideoHeightKey: imageSize.height]
            let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
            let adaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)

            if !videoWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            videoWriter.add(videoWriterInput)

            videoWriter.startWriting()
            let timeScale: Int32 = 600 // recommended in CMTime for movies.
            let startFrameTime = CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 600)
            let endFrameTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(movieLength, preferredTimescale: timeScale)
            videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startFrameTime)

            guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            let buffer: CVPixelBuffer = self.pixelBuffer(fromImage: cgImage, size: imageSize)!

            while !adaptor.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData { usleep(10) }
            let first = adaptor.append(buffer, withPresentationTime: startFrameTime)
            while !adaptor.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData { usleep(10) }
            let second = adaptor.append(buffer, withPresentationTime: endFrameTime)

            videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
            videoWriter.finishWriting {
                completion(true)
            }
        } catch {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "I don't get any video". But you are not asking for any video. You just say `let imageAsset = AVAsset(url: urlDestination)` and then stop, throwing away `imageAsset`. If this is not your real code, it does us no good. My guess is that you do something further. Show it!

Comment: Hey @matt, I've added the extra code. Always hard to find the balance between providing too much context and not enough. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: OK, so you are saying `let imageAsset = AVAsset(url: url)` followed immediately by `imageAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first`. So maybe the problem is that you didn't ask for asynchronous loading of the tracks. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading

Comment: From the documentation it does seem like I should be doing that. In trying it, I'm finding no change however. I changed my asset-video-composition-layer code to be within `loadValuesAsynchronously` with the following keys. When checking them all with `statusOfValue(forKey`, they all indicate they are loaded successfully without error.

let keys = ["playable", "readable", "composable", "tracks", "exportable"]

I have updated my code above to reflect these changes.

Comment: Darn. So what happens? Do you hit the assertion failure?

Comment: No, it doesn't fail on retrieving the imageVideoTrack -- one is retrieved and it even has a naturalSize and duration; but on presentation nothing is shown and a video doesn't seem to have been fetched for the AVPlayerViewController (the videoPlayer has a crossed-out play button where the video normally is and instead of a time in the bottom menu there is a spinner.

Comment: Ok I see there has been some discussion of this sort of thing, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762142/avplayer-does-not-play-video-instantly-on-ios-10-while-audio-playing-only Maybe some searching will be useful.